# Pass variables between two different pages with GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

i'm trying to get custom dimensions and metrics with GA from one page to other. Is there some method that i can use like .get() method that used in this example for clientId :

```
ga(function(a) {clientId = a.get("clientId"); })
```

I mean, if i have some 'dimension5' how can i get it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to retrieve data this way using Google Analytics. You will need to use cookies, session, or some other method (outside of GA) to pass data across pages like that.

If I am misunderstanding your question, please elaborate with more information.

Comment: i mean if i want to pass some info about user to GA and then get it back from GA but on other page

Comment: It may technically be possible but there is nothing to guarantee that when you send the data on the first page, it will be ready to be extracted (via the GA API) on the next page. It takes time for GA to process data (up to 48 hours). Ultimately, if you sent the data to GA yourself, it means that this data probably exists on your server. So you should be able to just grab it again from your server on the second page. GA is not designed to be a database.